# Comparison of PHP/Yii controllers

Tags: php, mvc, comparative-review, yii

I was recently asked to write a Question-and-Answer feature for my company's product pages using Yii 1. It was my first Yii project, and it was a little rough around the edges (Code A). However, when I submitted my code, my boss rewrote my two actions to a single action (Code B).

Both Code A and Code B work, but, in general, which one is better and why?

**Code A:**

```
/**
 * Creates a new question (and answer if given)
 *
 * @access  public
 * @throws  CDbException
 * @return  void
 *
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    // create form model
    $model = new QuestionForm('create');

    // if the form was submitted
    if (isset($_POST['QuestionForm'])) {
        // set the attributes
        $model->attributes = $_POST['QuestionForm'];
        // if the model is valid
        if ($model->validate()) {
            // create a new question
            $question = new CustomerQuestion();
            $question->employee_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
            $question->question    = $model->question;
            $question->pseudonym   = $model->questionPseudonym ?: null;
            $question->type        = $model->questionType;
            $question->status      = $model->questionStatus;
            // if the question is saved ok
            $isOk = $question->save();
            if ($isOk) {
                // create a new answer
                $answer = new CustomerAnswer();
                $answer->author_employee_id    = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $answer->customer_question_id  = $question->id;
                $answer->answer                = $model->answer;
                $answer->pseudonym_employee_id = $model->answerPseudonymEmployeeId ?: null;
                // if the answer is saved ok
                $isOk = $answer->save();
                if ($isOk) {
                    // loop through each item id
                    $insertItemIds = $model->getAuthenticInsertItemIds();
                    foreach ($insertItemIds as $itemId) {
                        // create a new question item
                        $questionItem = new CustomerQuestionItem();
                        $questionItem->item_id              = $itemId;
                        $questionItem->customer_question_id = $question->id;
                        // if an error occurs, stop
                        $isOk = $questionItem->save();
                        if ( ! $isOk) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    // if great success!
                    if ($isOk) {
                        // flash the good news and redirect to question/index
                        Yii::app()->user->setFlash(
                            'success', 
                            'Your question was created successfully'
                        );
                        $this->redirect($this->createUrl('question/index'));
                    } else {
                        $model->addErrors($questionItem->getErrors());
                    }
                } else {
                    $model->addErrors($answer->getErrors());
                }
            } else {
                $model->addErrors($question->getErrors());
            }
        }
    }

    // get all the employees
    $employees = Employee::model()
        ->scpIsActive()
        ->scpOrderFirstName()
        ->findAll();

    // create the view
    $this->render('create', [
        'employees' => $employees,
        'model'     => $model
    ]);

    return;
}

/**
 * Updates an existing question
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return
 *
 */
public function actionUpdate($questionId)
{
    // if the question id is valid
    if (is_numeric($questionId) && is_int(+$questionId) && $questionId > 0) {
        // if the question is authentic
        $question = CustomerQuestion::model()->findByPk($questionId);
        if ( ! empty($question)) {
            // create a new form model
            $model = new QuestionForm('update');
            // get the question's "old" item ids
            $oldItemIds = [];
            foreach ($question->Items as $item) {
                $oldItemIds[] = $item->id;
            }
            // set the starting value of the model's attributes
            $model->question       = $question->question;
            $model->questionType   = $question->type;
            $model->questionStatus = $question->status;
            $model->itemIds        = implode(', ', $oldItemIds);
            // get the question's first answer...
            //
            // a question can have multiple answers
            // however, we only support a single answer for now
            // it's a simpler workflow, and our staff answers are definitive
            // if a question doesn't have an answer, $answer will not be set
            //
            foreach ($question->CustomerAnswers as $answer) {
                break;
            }
            if (isset($answer)) {
                $model->answer                    = $answer->answer;
                $model->answerPseudonymEmployeeId = $answer->pseudonym_employee_id;
            }               
            // if the form was submitted
            if (isset($_POST['QuestionForm'])) {
                // create the form model
                $model->attributes = $_POST['QuestionForm'];
                // if the form is valid
                if ($model->validate()) {
                    // save the question's old status
                    $oldStatus = $question->status;
                    // update the question's attributes
                    $question->question  = $model->question;
                    $question->pseudonym = $model->questionPseudonym ?: null;
                    $question->type      = $model->questionType;
                    $question->status    = $model->questionStatus;
                    // if the question is saved ok
                    $isOk = $question->save();
                    if ($isOk) {
                        // determine what to do with the answer...
                        //
                        // how we handle the answer depends on several factors
                        // if the question had an answer and has an answer, update it
                        // if the question didn't have an answer and does now, insert it
                        // if the question had an answer and doesn't now, raise an error
                        // too much has happened with an answer to delete it
                        // 
                        $hadAnswer = ! empty($answer);
                        $hasAnswer = ! empty($model->answer);
                        if ($hadAnswer && $hasAnswer) {
                            // update the existing answer
                            $answer->answer                = $model->answer;
                            $answer->pseudonym_employee_id = $model->answerPseudonymEmployeeId ?: null;
                            $isOk = $answer->save();
                        } elseif ($hasAnswer) {
                            // create a new answer
                            $answer = new CustomerAnswer();
                            $answer->customer_question_id  = $question->id;
                            $answer->author_employee_id    = Yii::app()->user->id;
                            $answer->answer                = $model->answer;
                            $answer->pseudonym_employee_id = $model->answerPseudonymEmployeeId ?: null;
                            $isOk = $answer->save();
                        } elseif ($hadAnswer) {
                            // try to update the existing answer
                            // this will raise a validation error (and that's ok)
                            $answer->answer                = null;
                            $answer->pseudonym_employee_id = $model->answerPseudonymEmployeeId ?: null;
                            $isOk = $answer->save();
                        } else {
                            $answer = null;
                        }
                        // if whatever we did (or didn't do) to the answer is ok
                        if ($isOk) {
                            // get the items to delete
                            $deleteItemIds = $model->getDeleteItemIds($oldItemIds);
                            foreach ($deleteItemIds as $itemId) {
                                // find the question-item
                                $questionItem = CustomerQuestionItem::model()
                                    ->findByAttributes([
                                        'item_id'              => $itemId, 
                                        'customer_question_id' => $question->id
                                    ]);
                                // if the question-item is not deleted ok, break
                                $isOk = $questionItem->delete();
                                if ( ! $isOk) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            // if there were no deletes or they were all successfull
                            if ($isOk) {
                                // get the items to insert
                                $insertItemIds = $model->getAuthenticInsertItemIds($oldItemIds);
                                foreach ($insertItemIds as $itemId) {
                                    // create a new question-item
                                    $questionItem = new CustomerQuestionItem();
                                    $questionItem->item_id              = $itemId;
                                    $questionItem->customer_question_id = $question->id;
                                    // if the question-item is not saved ok, break
                                    if ( ! $questionItem->save()) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                // if ok
                                if ($isOk) {
                                    // if the question's status changed
                                    if ($question->status != $oldStatus) {
                                        // if the question was asked by a user
                                        // (i.e., don't send notifications to employees)
                                        //
                                        if ( ! empty($question->user_id)) {
                                            // send an email notification
                                            $this->sendMail($question, $answer);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // great success!
                                    // flash the user and redirect to question/index
                                    //
                                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash(
                                        'success', 
                                        'Your question was updated successfully'
                                    );
                                    $this->redirect($this->createUrl('question/index'));
                                } else {
                                    $model->addErrors($questionItem->getErrors());
                                }
                            } else {
                                $model->addErrors($questionItem->getErrors());
                            }
                        } else {
                            $model->addErrors($answer->getErrors());
                        }
                    } else {
                        $model->addErrors($question->getErrors());
                    }
                }
            }

            // get all the employees
            $employees = Employee::model()
                ->scpIsActive()
                ->scpOrderFirstName()
                ->findAll();

            // create the view
            $this->render('update', [
                'model'     => $model,
                'employees' => $employees
            ]);

        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(
                404, "A question with id '$questionId' does not exist"
            );
        }
    } else {
        throw new CHttpException(
            400, "A question id parameter is required"
        );
    }

    return;
}
```

**Code B:**

```
/**
 * Creates a new question (and answer if given)
 *
 * @access  public
 * @throws  CDbException
 * @return  void
 *
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $this->prepareAndSave( 'insert' );
}

/**
 * Updates an existing question
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return
 *
 */
public function actionUpdate($questionId)
{
    $this->prepareAndSave( 'update', CustomerQuestion::model()->findByPk( $questionId ) );
}

private function prepareAndSave( $type, $question=null )
{
    if ( ( $type !== 'insert' ) && ( $type !== 'update' ) )
        Throw New CHttpException( 400, "[Internal error] Unknown type sent to " . __FUNCTION__ . " in " . __CLASS__ . ": " . $type );

    $formModel = New QuestionFormModel( $type );
    $formModel->setQuestionId( $question ? $question->id : null );
    // If we try to load data into the formModel, but there is none to be found
    //   if this is an update and has a valid question, that information needs to be added to the formModel
    if ( $formModel->loadData() === false )
        $formModel->loadDataFromAR( $question );
    // If we are here, then the loadData() succeeded and data was sent that the formModel could use.
    //   Now we need to make sure the data is valid.  If it is valid we'll save it to the database.
    elseif ( $formModel->validate() === true )
    {
        // Everything should be good, time to save it to the database

        $questionStatusChanged = ( $question->status !== $formModel->questionStatus );

        // Prep and validate question
        if ( $question === null )
        {
            $question = New CustomerQuestion();
            $question->employee_id = Yii::user()->isGuest() ? 7 : Yii::user()->id;
        }
        $question->pseudonym = $formModel->questionPseudonym ?: null;
        $question->status    = $formModel->questionStatus;
        $question->type      = $formModel->questionType;
        $question->question  = $formModel->question;

        $questionValid = $question->validate();


        // Prep and validate answer
        $answer = null;
        $answerValid = false;
        if ( $questionValid && $formModel->hasAnswer() )
        {
            // Try to get answer model from existing question
            if ( $question->isNewRecord === false )
                $answer = $question->CustomerAnswer;

            $answerValidateList = null;

            // If no answer model exists, create a new one and load it with starting data.
            if ( $answer === null )
            {
                $answer = New CustomerAnswer();
                // ignore validating the customer_question_id initially if it is not yet available
                $answerValidateList = array_keys( $answer->attributes );
                if ( $question->isNewRecord )
                    $answerValidateList = array_diff( $answerValidateList, [ 'customer_question_id' ] );
                else
                    $answer->customer_question_id = $question->id;
                $answer->author_employee_id = $formModel->answerAuthorEmployeeId;
            }

            $answer->pseudonym_employee_id = $formModel->answerPseudonymEmployeeId ?: null;
            $answer->answer = $formModel->answer;

            $answerValid = $answer->validate( $answerValidateList );
        }

        // Question is valid.  Save question and questionItem.
        if ( $questionValid )
        {
            $question->save( false );

            $questionItemIdsToAdd = $formModel->itemIdList;
            foreach( $question->CustomerQuestionItems AS $qi )
            {
                // if an item id found in the database is in the add list, then remove it from the add list
                if ( in_array( $qi->item_id, $questionItemIdsToAdd ) )
                    $questionItemIdsToAdd = array_diff( $questionItemIdsToAdd, [ $qi->item_id ] );
                // if an item id found in the database is not in the add list, then remove it from the database
                else
                    $qi->delete();
            }
            // Everything left in the add list needs to be added to the database
            foreach( $questionItemIdsToAdd AS $itemId )
            {
                $qi = New CustomerQuestionItem();
                $qi->customer_question_id = $question->id;
                $qi->item_id = $itemId;
                $qi->save();
            }
        }

        // Answer is valid.  Save answer.
        if ( $answerValid )
        {
            $answer->customer_question_id = $question->id;
            $answer->save( false );
        }

        if ( ! $questionValid || ( $formModel->hasAnswer() && ! $answerValid ) )
        {
            $failureList = [];
            if ( ! $questionValid )
                $failureList[] = 'question';
            if ( ! $answerValid )
                $failureList[] = 'answer';
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash(
                'failure', 
                'An unknown error occured saving your ' . implode( ' and ', $failureList ) . '.  Please contact IT with the following information: '
                        . ( $question ? CHtml::errorSummary( $question ) : 'No problems with question.  ' )
                        . ( $answer ? CHtml::errorSummary( $answer ) : 'No problems with answer.  ' )
            );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( $questionStatusChanged )
                $this->sendMail( $question, $answer );
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash(
                'success',
                'Question ' . ( $answerValid ? 'and answer' : '' ) . ' updated successfully.'
            );
        }

        // Redirect to the update page for this question
        if ( $question->id )
            $this->redirect( [ 'question/update', 'questionId' => $question->id ] );
        else
            $this->redirect( [ 'question/create' ] );
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // This could be displayed if there is no data sent or if validation fails
    $this->render( 'edit', [
        'model'     => $formModel,
    ] );
}
```

Comment: For the improvements in code B i would prefer to have a cleaner layer of the controller and keep the model layer thick rather than writing all the model related code in the controller. There are still a lot of sections that could be moved into the model layer and shorten the code in the controller. i am talking about the `prepareAndSave`

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the removed duplicated code, the second version has other improvements too.

Instead of deeply nested `if ($isOk) { ... }` blocks, it has flattened the logic which is a lot more readable. And instead of `$isOK` which doesn't give a clue what it's about, he uses more meaningful names like `$questionValid` and `$answerValid`.

Note that this kind of repeated evaluation is well justified:

> ```
> if ( $questionValid ) {
>     // ...
> }
> if ( $answerValid ) {
>     // ...
> }
> if ( ! $questionValid || ( $formModel->hasAnswer() && ! $answerValid ) ) {
>     // ...
> }
> ```

You *might try* to rewrite this with nested conditions to avoid the repeated evaluation of `$questionValid` and `! $questionValid`, but the performance gain would be insignificant, and you would sacrifice readability.

I would recommend to go one step further, and decompose `prepareAndSave` to multiple functions. It's doing too many things:

- prepare question
- save question
- prepare answer
- save answer

These are different responsibilities, it would be good to extract them into independent functions, each responsible for one thing and one thing alone.

Comment: I agree with removing the duplicated code part, and I should have done a better job of that. However, I usually try to err on the side of KISS (aka, keep it stupid simple) over DRY (aka, don't repeat yourself).

Comment: Oh, and see, call me crazy, but I like nested if statements. They're like a checklist of tests that must be passed for the action to occur - kind of like the "One True Path". Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Deeply nested constructs are generally considered a bad idea, with few exceptions. And it's better to err on DRY than KISS. Simple is easier to refactor.

Answer (score 5):

In your code, if the business logic changes you have to make the change in two places and then you can make a mistake.

In your boss's code, the logic is in one place, so maintenance should be easier.

A better explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Comment: thanks for the answer. I totally agree with the DRY principle (and you), but to me, his code seemed harder to follow - i.e., the maintenance benefit gained in DRY was lost in KISS (keep-it-stupid-simple).

Answer (score 2):

Both examples, A & B are not very nice.

There is a lot of business logic in the controller. Code in controllers is not re-usable.

You can put the validation code into the model (as a method) to make it more re-usable.

In general:
Controllers should be small and contain little/less code
Models should contain all business logic including validation rules